# Fixing error in if (any(model$range < 0)) statement when fitting variogram in R?

Tags: r, modelling, variogram

I am using R and trying to fit a variogram model that I created:

```
 mod <- vgm(psill = var(newdfNoNAs$yield_cleaned),range= NA, model = 'Sph',nugget = 0)
```

And I used

```
 fit_reml <- fit.variogram.reml(yield_cleaned~1,data = newdfNoNAs,model = mod)
```

but it turns out

```
 Error in if (any(model$range < 0)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Can anyone tell me what it means and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you list the packages that you used because there are several kriging packages for R. I suspect this is `gstat`. Also, print out the `mod` object so we can see what values it has.

Comment: Yes this is `gstat`. `mod` outputs:  `model`    `psill range`
`1   Nug 0.000000     0`
`2   Sph 1.204258    NA` @Spacedman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
fit.variogram.reml            package:gstat            R Documentation

REML Fit Direct Variogram Partial Sills to Data

Description:

     Fit Variogram Sills to Data, using REML (only for direct
     variograms; not for cross variograms)
```

You've set range to NA, and this only fits sills, not ranges. Use `fit.variogram` or `fit.variogram.gls` if you want to fit all variogram parameters.

Comment: `fit <- fit.variogram(yield_cleaned~1,data=newdfNoNAs,model = mod)` returns error in `unused argument (data = newdfNoNAs)`. I am still waiting for the `fit.variogram.gls` result. Seems taking a while. @Spacedman

Comment: `fit.variogram.gls` runs very slowly. Do you have better solutions? @Spacedman

Comment: This is a solution to the question you asked. Mark it as answered, then start a new question about the speed of your variogram fitting because that requires new details about your data etc.